# How to use symbolic group name using re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, match, findall

Is it possible to access the symbolic group name defined in a regular expression with `(?P<toto>...)` with the equivalent of `re.findall()`?

Using `re.match()`, re returns a `MatchObject` on which the function `.group('toto')` can be used... I would like to do something close.

Here is an example :

```
import re
my_str = 'toto=1, bip=xyz, toto=15, bip=abu'
print re.findall('toto=(?P<toto>\d+)\,\sbip=(?P<bip>\w+)', my_str)
```

It returns :

```
[('1', 'xyz'), ('15', 'abu')]
```

I would like to get something like :

```
[{'toto':'1', 'bip':'xyz'}, {'toto':'15', 'bip':'abu'}]
```

Is there any simple way to do that?
I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that with `.findall()`. However, you *can* achieve the same effect with [`.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and some list comprehension magic:

```
print [m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer('toto=(?P<toto>\d+)\,\sbip=(?P<bip>\w+)', my_str)]
```

This prints:

```
[{'toto': '1', 'bip': 'xyz'}, {'toto': '15', 'bip': 'abu'}]
```

So we loop over each match yielded by `.finditer()` and take it's `.groupdict()` result.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly and I can even directly use it to loop on the iterator!